# Why there is no std::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, placement-new, noexcept

C++17 adds `std::uninitialized_move`, but there is no `std::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept` that would use `std::move_if_noexcept` internally. In my opinion, it would be useful, since now, if we want to reallocate, we still need to write something as

```
if constexpr (!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<value_type>
              && std::is_copy_constructible_v<value_type>)
  std::uninitialized_copy(...);
else 
  std::uninitialized_move(...);
```

Are there any particular reasons why `std::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept` was not introduced in C++17?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A paper on ["Extending memory management tools"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r2.html) at [open-std.org](http://www.open-std.org/) has a section on `uninitialized_move` which deals with this matter.

> Some concern is raised about exception handling with respect to `uninitialized_move`. If a move-constructor throws, the source object may have been irreparably damaged. As there is no solution to this problem, we implement the natural and expected semantics of destroying all fully constructed objects in the destination buffer and propagating the exception. This matches the behavior of `uninitialized_copy` as closely as possible.
>   **An additional algorithm, `uninitialized_move_if_noexcept`, could be considered as a resolution to this concern**. Such an algorithm was found already implemented in libstdc++ using a `move_if_noexcept` iterator. **Given that there is currently no range-based `move_if_noexcept` algorithm, such a solution is not considered here**. It seems clear that such a feature is readily possible, however.

Comment: What is `move_if_noexcept` iterator? There is only `std::move_iterator` in the Standard library, but no `std::move_if_noexcept_iterator`.

Comment: Methinks the paper is referring to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept

Comment: Actually, `uninitialized_move` could simply copy-assign all fully constructed objects from the destination buffer back to the source buffer, if the type is nothrow copy assignable. Then destroying all fully constructed objects in the destination buffer as it does anyway. This approach is also readily possible. This is still a weak/basic exception guarantee, but still better than leaving all fully moved-from objects in unspecified, but valid state. This way all the objects that could be revived is revived.